Cannot delete function because other objects depend on it
I'm trying to delete a function from my database but I get the following error:

Failed to delete database function: failed to delete pg.functions with the given ID: cannot drop function check_user_owns_character(uuid,uuid) because other objects depend on it

Where can I find where this function is referenced to update such references? This question is similar to Cannot DROP FUNCTION because it is being referenced by object except that that solution is T-SQL-specific.

If you try to delete a function that other objects depend on, Postgres tells you which object is in the way by default. Like (demo in psql):
test=> begin;  -- test in a transaction that can be rolled back to be sure
BEGIN
test=*> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.my_func(text);
ERROR:  cannot drop function my_func(text) because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  function f_other_func(text) depends on function my_func(text)
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.

(There may be more, in this case the next attempt shows the next blocking dependency.)
If you are sure you want to delete all depending objects you can just force that with:
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.my_func(text) CASCADE;

(Careful with that!)
Or you could look up the list of depending objects in a GUI like pgAdmin4. Chose the function in the object browser and pick the rider "Dependents".
For a more programmatic approach, you can get pointers to all depending objects from the system catalog pg_depend:
SELECT classid::regclass, *
FROM   pg_depend d
WHERE  d.refobjid = 'public.my_func(text)'::regprocedure;

Follow the link to the manual for a description of explanation on how to read these columns. I picked out classid::regclass to show the type of the depending object. For a function, this would be pg_proc ...
Of course, if the function to be dropped is used in the body of another PL/pgSQL function (which is stored as string, and only parsed at call time), no dependencies have been registered. It would be your responsibility to keep track of such dependencies ...
